# Increasingly long query times on stored procedure. - EXEC vs SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to that returns a set of rows about the data in a varbinary column. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why the query times always increase at the same rate when I use `sp_executesql` as opposed to `exec`.

Query with `sp_executesql` times go: <1s, 1s, 2s, 4s, 8s, 24s (etc) until, eventually, the problem "goes away" for a few minutes and the query is *always* ~0.006s

Query times with `exec` are always <500ms.

At first, I thought this was a problem with Linq2Sql, but when we ran the query Linq produces in SQL Management Studio, we got the same result.

Here's the body of the sproc (heavily censored)

Note that the `varbinary` column is not being pulled

```
select DF.FileID, 
       DF.DerpFkGuid, 
       DF.DerpName, 
       DF.[FileName],
       DF.FileSize as 'FileSizeBytes', 
       ISNULL(DFA.File_Size_Bytes_String,'Unknown') as 'FileSizeFriendly', 
       CONVERT(nvarchar(30),DF.FoundDate,120) as 'FileDateUploaded', 
       CONVERT(nvarchar(30),DF.FileDateCreated,120) as 'FileDateCreated',
       CONVERT(nvarchar(30),DF.FileDateLastModified,120) as 'FileDateModified',
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(dfa.Derp_ID,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as 'AttachedToDerp', 
       ISNULL(dfa.Derp_ID,'{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}') as 'Derp_ID'
from DerpFiles DF   
inner join DFDerpDerp DFdd      on DFdd.DerpName = DF.DerpName
left outer join Derp_Files_Attachments dfa      on dfa.FileID =  DF.FileID
where WR.UserName = @UserName and DF.DuplicateFileDetected=0
```

**Here is the code that runs consistently  < 500ms**

```
USE [DerpDatabase]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[DerpSproc]
        @UserName = N'derp',
        @DomainName = N'derp'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

**Here is the code that runs 1s ,2s ,4s, 8s , 24s, etc**

```
declare @p5 int
set @p5=0
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC   @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[DerpSproc] 
                            @UserName = @p0, 
                            @DomainName = @p1',                         
                            N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),
                            @p1 nvarchar(4000),
                            @RETURN_VALUE int output',
                            @p0=N'derp',
                            @p1=N'derp',
                            @RETURN_VALUE=@p5 output
select @p5
```

As far as I can tell, the 2 ways the sprocs are being called are essentially the same. The only difference is `sp_executesql` vs `exec`

It also appears that `exec` will produce the same increasing query times without the `go` keyword at the end. I can't tell for sure because I don't know if the query just happened to cache when I tried adding `go`?

Comment: The whole reason for using `sp_executesql` is to take advantage of statement caching, and as far as I know that's the ONLY difference it has with `exec`. So I'd wager this issue is somehow triggering a bug in the way cached queries are processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a parameter sniffing issue. Sometimes when you pass parameters into a procedure, SQL has a hard time figuring out how to use them efficiently. Try setting your parameters to local variables in the procedure, and then use the local variables in the where clause.

[Parameter Sniffing](http://www.sqloptimizationsschool.com/Troubleshooting/Parameter%20Sniffing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We solved our problem by moving the `VARBINARY` field from the files table to its own dedicated table. We cannot add a proper relationship between the file table and the metadata table without the query times going through the roof.

This only happens when we execute the query as a stored procedure. This does not happen when we do the same exact query as a view with a `WHERE` clause for our filters. Our mildly educated theory is that SQL Server 2012 has a bug(?) that causes the `VARBINARY` field in a table that we join against to be read on our query even though it's not included in our `SELECT` statement.